# Syntax or construct to simplify if() statement?

Tags: syntax, scope, conditional-statements, control-flow

I'm looking for a semantic or language construct that will simplify some of my `if` statements. If I have an if statement with an or, where I 'choose' between two values, I'd like to have that chosen variable available later on in the code.

I'll write this in pseudo-code:

```
if ( x or y ) {
    function(z);
}
```

Where `z` is the value of  `x` or `y`, whichever triggered the `if` to be true. Otherwise I'm writing

```
if ( x ) {
    ...
    function(x);
} 

if ( y ) { 
    ...
    function(y);
}
```

Now in that example the duplication isn't much, but in my actual situation, there are about 6 lines of code that would be identical duplication within each `if` block. So I write something like:

```
if ( x )  {
    z = x;
} 

if ( y ) {
   z = y;
}

if ( z ) {
    ...
    function(z);
}
```

But that just seems so roundabout I suspect that somewhere along the line some guru came up with a nice syntax to make a one-line `if`. Is there a construct in a language anywhere where I can bind the triggering value into a variable in the subsequent block? What would this structure be called?

The actual situation I'm working in is in PHP, so I realize PHP may not have this capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python (also Ruby), the expression `x or y` evaluates to `x` if it is true, otherwise `y`. You could write the statement as `f(x or y)`, or `z = x or y`.

Comment: Thanks, jleedev, this is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a name for this construct?

Answer (score 1):

For this exact situation. You can use the `?` operator:

```
z = x ? x : y;
```

Which reads: z is (if x is not false) x otherwise it is y.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, something like

```
if ( $z = ( $x ? $x : $y ) ) {
    function($z);
}
```

Works as advertised in PHP. Thanks, slebetman!